# Adding labs to ggplot when element_blank has been used

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I add x-axis label 'New x-lab' in the same family font to a ggplot2 object where `element_blank` has been used? `xlab` and `labs` does not seem to work.

```
library(ggplot2)

iris_p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, col = Species)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(family = 'Times'))
```

**EDIT:**

I am fully aware I can change the original code. I would like to add a lab to the object iris_p without changing the first part of the code.

Comment: So what you want to do is to not show the title of the y-axis?

Comment: Delete your `axis.title = element_blank()` ?

Comment: Just directly go to `axis.title.x = ...` and `axis.title.y = element_blank()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `iris_p` is the output from some function, which you can't change directly (otherwise this seems like a rather convoluted exercise), you can add another `theme()` component to the plot, specifying the full `element_text()` for `axis.title.x`:

```
# I'm referencing the default theme_grey parameters here
iris_p + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(family = "Times", face = "plain", 
                                    colour = "black", size = 11, lineheight = 0.9, 
                                    hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, angle = 0, 
                                    margin = margin(), debug = FALSE)) +
  xlab("some x axis label")
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element_blank()` partially on the graphic.
For that, you can just specify `theme(axis.title.y= element_blank())`, then the x.axis can be renamed in a normal way